# New Google Firebase dependency not detecting

Tags: android, firebase

New Google Firebase 2.9 dependency not detecting 
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `9.0.0` versions of the `com.google.android.gms:*` and `com.google.firebase:*` packages were just released in the SDK manager so it's likely you just need to update.

In Android Studio:

- Click Tools > Android > SDK Manager
- Click into the SDK Tools tab
- Select and install Google Play Services (rev 30) and Google Repository (rev 26).
- Sync and Build your project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your SDK Manager.

[image]

Also you have to use

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

in your `buildscript` block